# Eigenvalues of Differences of Hermitian Matrices $A, B$ When Trace $Tr(A - B) = 0$

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, singular-values, hermitian-matrices

Let's say we have two Hermitian matrices $A$ and $B$. We know the eigenvalues of both $A$ and $B$. We also know that $A - B$ is traceless, meaning:

$$
Tr(A - B) = 0.
$$

A piece of additional information that we know is, the eigenvalues of $A - B$ are all the same, up to change of sign. More specifically, if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A - B$, then $-\lambda$ is also an eigenvalue with the same multiplicity.

With these pieces of information, what can we say about $\lambda$? I am aware of this mathoverflow [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/4224/eigenvalues-of-matrix-sums) along with the Weyl inequalities. However, I believe there is something stronger that could be said in this specific situation. Could you please point to some directions? Thanks!

Comment: The symmetry of eigenvalues of $A-B$ that you describe implies immediately that $\operatorname{Tr}(A-B) = 0$. So, it's not an additional information (which is not what you claim, though).

Comment: @Alphie The question is: what can be said about the $\lambda$ in dependence of the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$? In your example, the Knutson-Tao inequalities tell us everything about the eigenvalues of $A-B$.